Mathematical proof that the earth is round.
Aristotle in his treatise on the heavens proves that the earth is round as follows : he observed lunar eclipses and noticed that only a round sphere could imply a circular shadow, so the earth is round. In modern terms, he says that if $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$ is a variety (differential or algebraic, as you prefer) such that the image of $X$ under all the projections $\pi:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ is a disk then $X$ is a round ball. Do you know a proof of this fact ?

Erathosthenes proved this with shadow lengths in different cities , in fact he even calculated surprisingly precise the circumference.

See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39127/is-the-sphere-the-only-surface-with-circular-projections-or-can-we-deduce-a-sp

"under all the projections"... as a tangent, I am wondering how Aristotle assume during an eclipse the projection seen would be representative of all possible projections.  As @MikhailKatz points out are flat round disk would eclipse as well, as would anything with a round cross-section.... but I digress.  That math overflow seems what you are looking for.

@fleablood The point would be that the projection changes at different times and remains circular throughout. Perhaps not every possible projection is achieved but enough to rule out, for example, a disk which would only provide a circular projection from one direction. Namely, it would be circular if the Earth, Sun and Moon were in a line (Syzygy) and only then if the disk lay perpendicular to that line but in other directions it would be elliptic

As pointed out by Travis Willse in the comments, this was answered on MathOverflow:

Let AB be the longest segment with endpoints on the surface. We may assume that its length equals 2 and its midpoint is the origin. Consider projections to the planes that contain AB. Since projections do not increase distances, AB is a diameter of each projection. Hence all projections to this family of planes are unit discs centered at the origin. The intersection of the corresponding cylinders is the unit ball, hence the result.

So $X$ is contained in the unit ball and contains its boundary. But there are real algebraic varieties and manifolds (with or without boundary) that satisfy this and aren't exactly the unit sphere, for example the union of the unit sphere with another sphere around the origin of smaller radius. Similarly there are other examples if you assume $X$ is a semi-algebraic set, eg a shell. As the MO post mentions, it is enough to assume that $X$ is convex to deduce that $X$ is exactly the unit ball.
